# Is it possible to update an incoming contact time for accepting or declining incoming calls in Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-connect

I'm working with an Amazon Connect based application, For that I implemented Amazon-connect-streams in our code to receive and accept calls.

By default, when Amazon Connect routes a call to an agent, the agent has 20 seconds to accept or decline incoming contact.

I want to increase the 20 seconds to 50 seconds and give more time to an agent to accept or decline incoming calls.

Any suggestion or help for it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, unfortunately. [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/configure-agents.html)

Comment: Thank you @gamliela for the reply, Is there any alternative solution for it?

Comment: Implement lambda logic that put agents back on available state if they miss a call. If they are the single agent on the queue they will get another chance to receive the call. Note it will affect your missed calls metrics.

Comment: You are right. But while calling lambda, amazon connect will routes to another agent.

Comment: Correct, as I wrote this workaround only works if they're the only agent on that queue.